# The meaning of (*rhs.m_pData)

Tags: c++, pointers

I would like to make sure if my understanding is correct.

I was studying about this code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// modified largely from
// http://d.hatena.ne.jp/toburau/20090722/1248283158

/*
class Test {
public:
    Test& operator=(const Test& rhs);
};
Test& Test::operator=(const Test& rhs)
{
    if (this == &rhs) return *this;          // *****
};
*/

//-----------------------------------------------------

class Data
{
    int num;
public:
    Data(void) : num(0) { }
    Data(int _num) : num(_num) { }
    Data(const Data &rhs) {
        cout << "copy constructor is called" << endl;
        num = rhs.num;
    }
    void show(void) {
        cout << num << endl;
    }
};

class CopyTest {
    Data *m_pData;
public:
    CopyTest(void) {
        m_pData = new Data(0);
    }
    CopyTest(int _num) {
        m_pData = new Data(_num);
    }
    void show(void) {
        m_pData->show();
    }
    CopyTest& operator=(const CopyTest& rhs);
};

CopyTest& CopyTest::operator=(const CopyTest& rhs) /*****/
{
    Data *p = m_pData;
    m_pData = new Data(*rhs.m_pData); // case 0 // OK // copy constructor is called
//  m_pData = new Data(*(rhs.m_pData)); // case 1 // OK
//  m_pData = new Data(*(rhs).m_pData)); // case 2 // NG
    delete p;
    return *this;
}


int main() {
    CopyTest cpyObjA, cpyObjB(31);

    cpyObjA.show();
    cpyObjB.show();

    cout << "## after" << endl; 
    cpyObjA = cpyObjB;
    cpyObjA.show();
    cpyObjB.show();

    return 0;
}
```

see 
http://ideone.com/7qnzLP 
for code with line numbers and coloring.

In this code (line 53), there is a code like

```
 m_pData = new Data(*rhs.m_pData); // case 0
```

Does this mean the case 1 not case 2?

```
 m_pData = new Data(*(rhs.m_pData)); // case 1
 m_pData = new Data(*(rhs).m_pData); // case 2
```

In this kind of code, what kind of writing style do you recommend among case 0-2 or other?

Comment: Case 1 and case 2 are the same.  Did you mean to ask about `(*rhs).m_pData`?

Comment: No. I mean as writen above (*(rhs).m_pData).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean the case 1 not case 2?
>
> m_pData = new Data(*(rhs.m_pData)); // case 1
>
> m_pData = new Data(*(rhs).m_pData); // case 2

It means case 1.

> In this kind of code, what kind of writing style do you recommend among case 0-2 or other?

I always avoid redundant parentheses, indeed redundant anything.

Comment: Thank you, EJP. When I compile case2, I receive error (as written in the reply to zybjtu. I wonder whether this happens only for ideone.com or not.

Comment: Case 2 is meaningless. `(rhs)` can't be a pointer as in `*(rhs)` if it is also legal to use it as a struct name with the `.` operator.

Comment: @KepaniHaole 'Offensive' is entirely the wrong word. 'Nonsense' is what I said, and what I meant. Operator overloading is a semantic matter, nothing to do with syntax whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Your `case 1` is the same with `case 2`. In c++, the priority level of `'.' operator` is high than `'*' operator`, your parentheses doesn't change the priority level. And both `case 1` and `case 2` are right.
I thought what you want to say is 
`m_pData = new Data((*rhs).m_pData);`, which is wrong.
You can read the table of operator priority:[level.http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: Thank you zybjtu and Ben Jackson. I also thought case 1 and case 2 were same. But when I remove comment for case 2, I receive following errors: *************"prog.cpp: In member function ‘CopyTest& CopyTest::operator=(const CopyTest&)’:
prog.cpp:55:36: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
  m_pData = new Data(*(rhs).m_pData)); // case 2 // NG"************